# Fourier transform: noise and variance

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing, noise

I wrote a short program to generate $N$ samples of a sinusoid with some noise (ie:

$$ f(t) = \cos(2\pi t) + 0.1 * \text{noise}(t) $$

where $\text{noise}(t)$ is chosen uniformly from $[-1 , 1]$.

Here is an example of $f(t)$ with 1000 samples:

[image: Sample plot of f(t)]

Then I found the amplitude of the fundamental using the Discrete Fourier Transform:

$$ 2F(1) = \frac{2}{N} \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1} f(\frac{n}{N}) e^{-i2\pi n/N} $$

I got my program to randomly generate this function 100 times and found the mean and standard deviation of the calculated fundamental. I ran this process using anywhere from 100 to 20000 samples. Here is a plot of my results (the points are the means and the error bars are the standard deviations):

[image: DFT results]

The means of this plot are close to 1, as I would expect (the sinusoid has an amplitude of 1). However, the standard deviation is decreasing as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$ (I got this from a log-log plot).

I can't figure out why the standard deviation changes with the number of samples! It intuitively makes sense that more samples = more precision, but I know that white noise has the same power at all frequencies.

**Mathematically, why does the effect of noise decrease when I add more samples to the DFT?**

Comment: Central limit theorem is strong me thinks

Comment: You would probably find [this post about the Fourier transform of white noise](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/24170/what-is-the-statistics-of-the-discrete-fourier-transform-of-white-gaussian-noise) interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essentially, you are computing $\hat F_{k_1} = F_{k_1} + E_{k_1}$ where $F_k$ is the clean Fourier transform, and $E_k$ is the Fourier transform of $e(n)=0.1 \, n(t)$ - the noise.

By [Parseval theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem#Notation_used_in_engineering_and_physics), $\sum |e(n)|^2 =N\sum |E_k|^2 $. (Note that the linked formula has a $N$ in the denominator - the difference arises because you are using a normalized Fourier transform instead of the [usual definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Definition))

But $\sum |e(n)|^2 \approx N \sigma^2_e$ (assuming stationary iid noise) and $\sum |E_k|^2 \approx N |E_{k_1}|^2$ (assuming white noise, which have same energy in all frequencies). Putting all together, and assuming $N$ is large enough (so we can replace approximations by equalities), we get

$$ N \sigma^2_e = N^2 \, |E_{k_1}|^2 \implies |E_{k_1}| = \sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2_e}{N}}$$

As @Chinny84 comments, this can be seen as a consequence of the CLT, or, more elementarily, from the well-known fact that the [variance of the sample mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sum_of_uncorrelated_variables_.28Bienaym.C3.A9_formula.29)  decreases as $1/N$. Parseval theorem roughly tells us that averaging in frequency is the same as averaging in time.

Comment: Perfect! This is roughly where my train of thought was going - it's great to see it formalized.

Comment: I read in an article the following: "signal variability was determined by calculating the
standard deviation (SD) of preprocessed time series that was bandpassed at 0.01 to 0.1Hz. According to Parseval's theorem, this approach is equivalent to
the frequency-domain computation of the amplitude of low-frequency
fluctuations (ALFF) at 0.01 Hz to 0.1 Hz.". Is this true?